# What's the best way to figure out which javascript code that change specific html content in page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have `<p>` tag in my webpage and i am trying to find out which JavaScript function that adding text inside this element, is there any specific way in chrome to add listener on this tag to find out which script that writing on this tag?

Comment: The one way I know how to do this is using the timeline i developer tools (f12). So set it to record, click or do some action to change a function and then look through and see if you can find the function

Comment: You can use "Developers Tool > Profile > Collect JavaScript CPU Profile" and check which function is executing

Comment: @JagsSparrow I like your solution but it doesn't specify which element was changed by the listed actions.

Comment: It will not, but it will reduce lookup area of code

Comment: @JagsSparrow Yes you are right i voted up your answer, but i think there's better way to find the sneaky beaky script :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct (low noise) way uses a sync pause that lets you poke around in the whole call stack:

1. Open chrome's devtools.
2. Right-click the element in the devtools "Elements" tab to reveal the context menu
3. Choose Break On... > Subtree Modifications.

Once the element's "innerHTML" changes, the script execution will pauses and you can view the whole call stack in the "Sources" tab, including whatever function requested the DOM change.

Certain DOM modifications like animation libraries can use a `setTimeout` or callback that discards much of the call stack that lead up to the change, and in those cases, a Profile might be more interesting, since the animation function should stand out like a sore thumb in a "Heavy" view.