# What is a good way to find what script on a webpage added a certain element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, breakpoints, firefox-developer-tools

I am fiddling around with a certain webpage and I have found a script element on that page that I wish to find the origin of, and what is calling it. Is there a good way to do this using firefox's dev tools? I have tried setting some DOM breakpoints but they go away when I reload the page.

Comment: The network tab should tell the resource.

Comment: @Andy I realize that it should contain which one is doing it. The problem is they are all obfuscated and there are quite a lot of them. Is there a way to search through all loaded resources with firefox dev tools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to figure out which javascript code that change specific html content in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045429/whats-the-best-way-to-figure-out-which-javascript-code-that-change-specific-htm)

Comment: @SebastianZartner Maybe, I’ll see if the profiler will do the trick.